# Mailserver at my hosting company is unable to resolve certain domains

Tags: web-hosting, email, shared-hosting, hostgator

I am hosting my site on HostGator. The problem is that I can not receive e-mails from some domains.

Here is the SMTP transaction response received:

```
H=(sv2.elanceonline.com) [162.242.179.29]:38251 I=[192.185.51.218]:25 F=<bounce@svbounce.elanceonline.com> temporarily rejected RCPT

H=(sv2.elanceonline.com) I=[192.185.51.218]:25 sender verify defer for <bounce@svbounce.elanceonline.com>: host lookup did not complete
Unable to resolve svbounce.elanceonline
```

The support person at HostGator insisted that the problem is on domain-side, but I am very sure it is on HostGator's side because I never had any such problems before using HostGator, and now in the course of 2 days I'm having the same problem with 2 different senders.

I can receive from both domain's emails to Gmail at the same time without any problem, but once I type `myemail@mydomain.com` (`mydomain.com` is hosted on HostGator) I cannot receive e-mail.

What could be reasons for not being able to resolve `svbounce.elanceonline` or other domains? Should I trust HostGator and believe them that it's not a problem on their side?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot post an image as a comment, but I can tell you the problem is on the domain side

[image: Elanceonline NSLOOKUP]

Move the mail server from the orange box to the blue one.  How you do that varies from host to host.  Until your MX record is fixed you can only send mail from an address in your domain to an address in your domain.  In case you cant see the image, I used the [NSLOOKUP tool](http://network-tools.com/nslook/) at http://network-tools.com/

**UPDATE** For Sake of Completeness, your SOA record cannot be empty.  See [What is an SOA Record?](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/soa-record/)  Your MX Record can also not be empty, again look at [What is an MX record?](http://support.dnsimple.com/articles/mx-record/)  Authority records should contain  the name and address of the registered owner for the domain.  If this is a company, it should be the person at the company who pays the monthly invoice, along with the web master's mailbox.  Additional records should be used for subdomains etc.

**UPDATE 2**
That would be correct, since the domain record can only be edited at Host Gator's Control Panel for said domain. Host Gator can say it is on the domain side, as they are not in charge of updating your records, but they are notorious for not telling you to update them.  GoDaddy and some of the more reputable ones make it Mandatory.  [See my domain record](http://network-tools.com/nslook/Default.asp?domain=carterswebs.com&type=255&server=67.222.132.198&class=1&port=53&timeout=5000&go.x=0&go.y=0).  As a courtesy, my host, put their email in my SOA, that way, if they can fix the issue they will, and will notify me afterwards.  If the issue is on my end, the host will issue a support ticket from the inside out (From them to me) and will pester me until it is closed.

---

No disrespect intended, but when you pay prices starting as low as 3.96/month, what kind of support do you expect?

Comment: I have this problem all the time. The solution is above... MX Records is the key.

Comment: But this should be done on Elance side, not Hostgator, right?

Comment: @ernest1a See Update 2